# QGIS how to batch process zonal statistics?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, zonal-statistics

I'm trying to figure out how to run "zonal statistics" in QGIS 3.8.2 (qgis:zonalstatistics) on multiple hundred shapefiless with building footprints and corresponding raster files (each share the same extends and filenames except for the extension). The aim to to weed out buildings that fall fully or partially within water.

What I have:

- Vector shapefiles with building footprints
- RGB raster files with watermasks (black = water, white = land)

The whole process should be rather simple with "zonal statistics".

For whatever reason however "zonal statistics" only writes the resulting values as new attributes into the existing shapefile when it is set as "editable". Which obviously doesn't work that simple for several hundred files in a row.
Running "zonal statistics" as a batch process works just fine, with the exception that nothing happens to processed files because they obviously haven't been set as "editable" on the fly while the process was running through them.

How can I either make several hundred shapefiles editable before running "zonal statistics" or have it apply the changes to a new set out output shapefiles?

Comment: Please specify which `zonal statistics` tool you are using: `qgis:zonalstatistics`, `grass7:r.stats.zonal` or `saga:zonalrasterstatistics`. At least the Saga-tool lets you specify an output file.

Comment: qgis:zonalstatistics

Comment: Then try the saga tool. It can be accessed via the tool box.